# How to dynamically loop through field names in an MVC Data Model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my database structure, I have an array of fields for a particular user.  Like...

`User: Choice1, Choice2, Choice3, Choice4, etc.`

When the View is posted to the controller, the values that will go into those fields are passed in a string array (`MyChoices[]`) from a dynamically constructed set of hidden inputs.

My brilliant idea was to use a `for` loop to go through the array and assign the values.  So, something like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < MyChoices.Count(); x++ {
  model.Choice[x + 1] = MyChoices[x];
}
```

But, I'm not having any luck figuring out how to dynamically get the field names out of the model so that I can assign them.

Essentially I'm looking for something like: `model.GetField("Choice" + x + 1)`

Is there any way to do this?  I was thinking about reforming my data structure so that, instead of listing out Choice1, Choice2, Choice3, etc., I just have a Choices table that lists User, ChoiceID, ChoiceValue.  But, I really don't wanna restructure my data, because I have another page where it's actually laid out in a table.  Is there a way to do this, or am I just breaking every Database/Developer commandment there is?

I know this is a fairly "How do you do this" type question, but I've been searching and haven't really found a solution... and I'm actually looking for C# syntax, so I think it qualifies.

Here is the Model class:

```
public partial class UserChoice
{
    public int UserChoiceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Choice1 { get; set; }
    public string Choice2 { get; set; }
    public string Choice3 { get; set; }
    public string Choice4 { get; set; }
    public string Choice5 { get; set; }
    public string Choice6 { get; set; }
    public string Choice7 { get; set; }
    public string Choice8 { get; set; }
    public string Choice9 { get; set; }
    public string Choice10 { get; set; }
    public string Choice11 { get; set; }
    public string Choice12 { get; set; }
    public string Choice13 { get; set; }
    public string Choice14 { get; set; }
    public string Choice15 { get; set; }
    public string Choice16 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the class, containing the Choice-thingy

Comment: I highly recommend you, to use a `List<string> Choices`. So you can iterate over that list

Comment: those arnt fields they are properties never the less check reflection in the documentation there is a GetProperties() method also

Comment: @lokusking - My issue isn't iterating through the actual values, it's iterating through the fields... er, "properties."

Comment: A big part of me still thinks I just need to reform my data so that it's not tabular.

Comment: Well this might be true, but if you'd redisign your `UserChoice`-Class you wouldnt have to use reflection. Furthermore, you dont need 16 Properties containing a string + its more easy to maintain

Comment: Well, I'm using data first because I'm building a new app over an existing database.  So, the model is automatically generated from the database.  That's why I'm trying to avoid having to reformat the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, here's how I did it:

First off, hats off to Halford... I mean, @Thorarins, because he pretty much led me in the right direction.  Essentially, I was able to accomplish my task with the following:

```
for (int x = 0; x < MyChoices.Count(); x++)
{
    td.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "Choice" + (x + 1)).SetValue(td, MyChoices[x]);
}
```

My end solutions here seem a little clunky and unnatural.  So, if anyone has any good ideas how to make it better, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have a clue what fields or properies that is comming you should use Reflection

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Sample:

```
            FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();

            for(int i = 0; i < myField.Length; i++)
            {                  
                    Console.WriteLine(myField[i].Name);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check this out.  And, you're not kidding... you actually have to USE reflection!  lol  Get it?  `using System.Reflection`... okay, sorry.  Bad programming joke.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the property names dynamically or on run time, you should use [System.Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx), you can even get or set their values